# How to make Fancybox work with carousel plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I use Fancybox and [Scrolling Carousel](http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/).
Try to make : click `$(.subject)`  into Fancybox  >  show `$(.content)` > `$(.content)` scroll use scrollingCarousel.

I did test works fine separate.

But if I put them together (Demo1). 
Why the `$(.content)` won't load scrollingCarousel?
(but if reload `$(.content)` page, then scrollingCarousel work.)

So I try to wrote in Fancybox callback (Demo2) afterLoad,beforeLoad,beforeShow... I did test too, still does't work.

(I've test other carousel plugin, same problem.)

Demo 1 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6VH7w/2/)

```
 $(".subject").fancybox({});
 $('.content').scrollingCarousel({});
```

Demo 2

```
 $(".subject").fancybox({
     afterLoad: function(){
        $('.content').scrollingCarousel({});
     }
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="subject">
    <div>
        <a class="subjectlist"rel="1" href="#1">
            <img class="" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_m.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content" id="1">
    <div><img class="" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7171/6417719753_374653e28c_b.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_b.jpg"></div>
    <div><img class="" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6106/6347065961_bb73745e70_m.jpg"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.content{
    display:none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.content img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}​
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery is only half the problem... where is relevant HTML code?  I think Demo 1 is the way to go and you probably have something wrong with your HTML or selectors.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is Demo1 looks like http://jsfiddle.net/6VH7w/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.content` is hidden by your CSS with `display: none`, so you simply have to show it using `.show()` before invoking the scroller, otherwise it just stays hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/6VH7w/3/

```
$(".subjectlist").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        $('.content').show().scrollingCarousel({
            scrollerAlignment: 'vertical'
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Hellow I made owl carousel 2 and fancybox, added fancybox css, mousewheel and js files. Then I made my items

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="item">
       <a class="fancybox" group="fancybox" href="imagen0.png"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" src="imagen0.png" title="SEJ" /></a>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <a class="fancybox" group="fancybox" href="imagen1.png"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail center-block" src="imagen1.png" title="titulos_imagen" /></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope this help you.